# Efficient way of minimizing memory footprint of set of numbers

Tags: c#

I'm writing code for an embedded device using .Net Micro Framework, I have a set of calculated integers as shown by the link below which I need to access but I'd like it if this information could be minimized somehow, basically I have a list of numbers ranging from 150 - 4, each number has an adjacent list of numbers that it can be linked to, ex 150 can be linked to 149, 148, 146, 144, 142 etc, some numbers (150 to 4) share linked numbers 150 & 149 share 91 as an example as well as many others, so I'm thinking there must be someway of representing all these numbers were the memory footprint is reduced since there are a lot of share linked numbers, any suggestions would be great.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqn8097571r9s27/LinkedNumbers.txt

Example Data

150 = 149, 148, 146, 144, 142, 140, 138, 136, 134, 99, 93, 92, 91, 87

149 = 148, 147, 145, 143, 141, 139, 137, 135, 133, 131, 129, 103, 102, 97, 96, 93, 92, 91

148 = 147, 146, 145, 144, 142, 140, 138, 136, 134, 132, 99, 97, 94, 92, 91, 88, 87, 86

147 = 146, 145, 144, 143, 141, 139, 137, 135, 133, 131, 95, 91, 90, 89, 88

Comment: include sample data in your question, it is highly likely links to file downloads will never be clicked

Comment: What is the algorithm that the number sequence complies to?

Comment: I don't think it would help to explain how these numbers are generated, I'm just hoping there's a way of compressing them down a bit

Comment: But without knowing the logic behind them we can't tell how to compress it.

Comment: the most obvious right now is that you only need 8bit for each of your numbers so you can pack 3 of them into an 32bit integer and 6 into an 64bit integer

Comment: Yes they are already generated from a Arraylist containing bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store each row as a 19 byte bit sequence where a one represents an entry in your list and a zero represents a value not in your list.

For example, your first entry is:-

```
150 = 149, 148, 146, 144, 142, 140, 138, 136, 134, 99, 93, 92, 91, 87,
      83, 79, 77, 65, 63, 59, 55, 54, 53, 51, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 
      43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 35, 34, 33, 31, 29, 27, 25, 23, 22, 
      21, 19, 18, 17, 14, 13, 12, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
```

can be store as:-

```
150 = 0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0.....
```

where the first bit is represents 0, the second represents 1, etc.

You can improve the efficiency of the storage by decreasing the number of bits used for each row, but the computation of the bit to check becomes a bit more complex. Using this, the whole lot can be stored in 1416 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, would this compress things down by a factor of 8?

Comment: @chillydk147: using a 2 dimensional array of bits, yes, you'd use one bit per value, so a factor of 8 is easy to do. If you use the triangular method it becomes a factor of 16.

Comment: What's the triangular method?

Comment: @chillydk147: where you decrease the number of values stored for each row. So the row for 150 has 149 numbers and row 4 has three numbers. If you created a table with 0-150 along the top and 1-150 down the side and put a 1 in the cell where the number of the row maps to the number of the column, half the grid would be empty - hence triangular. By taking advantage of the fact half the grid is empty, you can double the compression factor.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now, as the row numbers get smaller, they will have less adjacent numbers

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum decrement between two sequential numbers doesn't exceed, for instance, `64`, then you can store each sequence as a list of 6-bit unsigned decrement values.

Example:

```
150 = 149, 148, 146, 144, 142, 140, 138, 136, 134, 99, 93, 92, 91, 87
```

Becomes a:

```
150 =   1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2,   2, 35,  6,  1,  1,  4
```

Comment: Interesting, that should reducing it down a fair bit